# Fastversion Plugin

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-cloud

I have installed a fastversion plugin in QGIS 3.6 for versioning. It ask for login details and failed to connect.

Host:- local

port:- 5432

Database:- example temprory

user name :- system user

Password:- system user password

Qgis master password:- qgis master password

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code-repository as well as the homepage seem to be offline, i would guess the plugin is not maintained anymore (first and last version of the plugin are from 2019)

Comment: do you know an alternative?